# Stop event in c# through javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have page with 2 textboxes and button. When I press the button, some event appears on the server. But I need to check case if textboxes are empty. So I've made 2 events for button `onclick="Button1_Click" onclientclick="Button1_javaEvent()"`. In event Button1_javaEvent I check this case. Is it possible to stop Button1_Click in javascript if textboxes are empty and how???

```
 function Button1_javaEvent() {
        var flag = false;
        var message_str = "";
        if (main_form.Text_login.value == "") {
                message_str += "Enter the login";
                message_str += "\n";
                flag = true;
            }
         if (main_form.Password_login.value == "") {
                message_str += "Enter the password";
                flag = true;
             }
             if (flag == true) {
                 alert(message_str);
             }
             else {                  
                   ????????????         
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:

```
onclientclick="return Button1_javaEvent()"
```

Return true/false from `Button1_javaEvent()` function, if Button1_javaEvent() return true then postback will happen otherwise not.

[Refer online sample to test this](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_linkbutton_onclientclick.asp)

Comment: Button1_javaEvent is client side event

Answer (score 2):

In your javascript function return true if you want a postback and return false if you don't want a postback.

Like this:

```
function Button1_javaEvent() {
    var flag = false;
        var message_str = "";
        if (main_form.Text_login.value == "") {
                message_str += "Enter the login";
                message_str += "\n";
                flag = true;
    }

    if (main_form.Password_login.value == "") {
                message_str += "Enter the password";
                flag = true;
    }

    if (flag == true) {
        alert(message_str);
    }

    return !flag;
}
```

Comment: it's a bad idea to have multiple return statement in a function. store the value in variable to return and use that variable in return statement.